# How to align text center to left on canvas Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

I am developing Photography apps, and for that I am using this code:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
paint.setTextSize(50);
paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
// if the background image is defined in main.xml, omit this line
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
int left = measureTextWidth(paint, InstaTextActivity.CurrentWord);
int top = measureTextHeight(paint, InstaTextActivity.CurrentWord);

left = mBitmap.getWidth() / 2 - InstaTextActivity.textCount / 2;
top = mBitmap.getHeight() / 2 - InstaTextActivity.textCount / 2;
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(InstaTextActivity.CurrentWord, paint, total,
 android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, (float) 1.0, (float) 0.0, true);
//canvas.save();
canvas.translate(left, top);
layout.draw(canvas);
//canvas.restore();
```

In this code I am using `paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER)`.  It aligns to centre, but text doesn't align center to left, instead it aligns centre to right.  Also, what is the proper way to align text on canvas?

[image]

But I want

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Im using

```
StaticLayout mTextLayout = new StaticLayout(text, mTextPaint,
                canvas.getWidth(), Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0.0f,
                false);
canvas.translate((canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (mTextLayout.getWidth() / 2), (canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((mTextLayout.getHeight() / 2)));
```

to center my multi line text on a canvas

Comment: Why can't use pass Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER?

Comment: The *text centering* comes from the Paint object with `paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER)` 

The position (canvas.translate) is where you draw the static layout. It is also the base the reference by which the text alignment is happening.  In other words, you have to translate it in the middle of your canvas.  The other Alignment is for something else that I cannot put my finger on.  `ALIGN_NORMAL` is what you need here.

Comment: EDIT: nope, I was wrong. Something else is going on that I do not grasp.